# How to open a lightbox form from a navigation menu item

Tags: menus, customization, forms

I want to add a custom menu item to the main navigation menu, On clicking this item I want to open a lightbox form. I have the form-shortcode ready to be placed but on a page but I don't know how to do this in the main navigation menu, i have used cforms-II for the form and lightbox form to display it in lightbox modal. please help. i'm using wordpress 3.5
Note: I may need to change my theme in recent future so I would like the solution to programtically do this.Thanks.
Edit: I'm trying to use the following code:
`add_filter()` to add menu item, and for light box form i have this code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li>Show whatever</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}

[formlightbox_call title="Get free quote" class="4"]here[/formlightbox_call]
[formlightbox_obj id="4" style="padding: 10px; width:350px"][contact-form-7 id="848" title="Contact form 1"][/formlightbox_obj]
```

Comment: Show us what code you are working with, tell us more about the lightbox script you are working with too. It might be as simple as assigning a custom class to your menu item or it might require that you dig deeper into the use of [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and possible use a custom nav menu walker function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Goto

> Dashboard ->  Appearance -> Menus ->  screen options (See top corner)
>   -> Check css classes ->  Now add a custom class in your link ( Ex: lightboxlink )

Now add some jquery code in the footer like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".lightboxlink").click(function() {
  lightbox();
});
});
```

Comment: Just to point out, typically, you want to add the link value as "#lightbox_content" or whatnot, and output your lightbox'd content in wp_footer (with display none container around the div with the id="lightbox_content").